# populate dropdown inside of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, model-binding, dropdown

I'm hoping someone can help me. I have a gridview and inside that each line has a dropdown. I would like the dropdown populated based on the value of the lines key value.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCart" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped" DataKeyNames="UOMSCHDL" OnRowDataBound="gvCart_RowDataBound"
    SelectMethod="gvCart_GetData" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DeleteMethod="gvCart_DeleteItem" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Item #</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("ITEMNMBR")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>UOM</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUOM" runat="server"AutoPostBack="true" SelectMethod="getUOM" CssClass="dropdown-toggle"
                                            DataTextField="UOFM" DataValueField="UOFM" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code that populates the dropdown:

```
Public Function getUOM() As IEnumerable
    'the following code has a red sqiggly under RowIndex because it isn't 
    'declared. I get that, but what do I use to get the RowIndex

    Dim uom As String = gvCart.DataKeys(RowIndex).Value.ToString()

    'this query works if I "hardcode" the where to = "roll" but I want 
    ' it to be dynamic

    Dim query = From i In db.IV40202
                Where i.UOMSCHDL = uom ' "roll"
                Order By i.SEQNUMBR
    Return query.ToList()

End Function
```

As I commented in the code I don't know how to get the RowIndex.

Thank you in advanced for the help.

I thought I would post the completed solution for anyone that is interested.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>UOM</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUOM" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown-toggle"></asp:DropDownList>
         </ItemTemplate>
```

and in the code behind:

```
 Public Function getUOM(uom As String) As IEnumerable
    Dim myUOM As String = Trim(uom)
    'ultimately this needs to be based on the uomschdl of each item
    Dim query = From i In db.IV40202
                Where i.UOMSCHDL = myUOM ' "roll"
                Order By i.SEQNUMBR
                Select New With {
                    .UOFM = i.UOFM
                    }
    Return query.ToList()

End Function

Protected Sub gvCart_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim uom As String = gvCart.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString()
        Dim ddlUOM As DropDownList = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("ddlUOM"), DropDownList)
        ddlUOM.DataSource = getUOM(uom)
        ddlUOM.DataTextField = "UOFM"
        ddlUOM.DataValueField = "UOFM"
        ddlUOM.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to move your call to getUOM(rowIndex) in to your gvCart_RowDataBound handler like so:

```
protected Sub gvCart_RowDataBound(Dim sender As Object, Dim e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim rowIndex As Int = e.Row.RowIndex
    getUOM(rowIndex)        
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed this a bit so that it sends back the actual uom instead of the RowIndex. And this works, Except now the page lifecycle gets in the way of the results populating the dropdown. I think because the gvCart_RowDataBound happens just before the page is rendered, the dropdowns come back empty eventhough they were previously populated.

Comment: You need to bind them. I'm not sure of your exact requirement, but if you are initially loading them in, then performing some action that causes a postback, you'll need to rebind them again (which should happen automatically if you're correctly rebinding your grid).